# Snake can't get tail to correctly follow the head

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a simple snake game using JavaScript and JQuery.

I can't seem to get the tail to follow the head.

What my code does is, once the snake eats the food, expand in the direction it ate the food and the entire body moves in one cluster instead of in a following motion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: heres a codepen of the project: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmJWOa

```js
var snake = {
  position: [20, 20],
  direction: "r",
  current_snake: [
    [20, 20]
  ]
}

var food = {
  position: [10, 4]
}

var gameSpeed = 250;

function createGrid() {
  var grid = [];

  for (var row = 0; row < 40; row++) {
    for (var column = 0; column < 40; column++) {
      grid.push([row, column]);
    }
  }

  return grid;
}

function render() {
  var grid = createGrid();

  $.map(grid, function(variable, index) {
    $(".snake-grid").append("<div class='square' id='row-" + grid[index][0] +
      "-col-" + grid[index][1] + "'</div>");
    $("#row-20-col-20").addClass("snake");
    $("#row-10-col-4").addClass("food");
  })
}

function parseKey(key) {
  console.log(key);
  switch (key) {
    case 37:
      snake.direction = "l";
      break;
    case 38:
      snake.direction = "u";
      break;
    case 39:
      snake.direction = "r";
      break;
    case 40:
      snake.direction = "d";
      break;
  }
}

function move() {
  for (var i = 0; i < snake.current_snake.length; i++) {
    switch (snake.direction) {
      case "l":
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).removeClass("snake");
        snake.current_snake[i][1] = snake.current_snake[i][1] - 1;
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).addClass("snake");
        break;
      case "u":
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).removeClass("snake");
        snake.current_snake[i][0] = snake.current_snake[i][0] - 1;
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).addClass("snake");
        break;
      case "r":
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).removeClass("snake");
        snake.current_snake[i][1] = snake.current_snake[i][1] + 1;
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).addClass("snake");
        break;
      case "d":
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).removeClass("snake");
        snake.current_snake[i][0] = snake.current_snake[i][0] + 1;
        $("#row-" + snake.current_snake[i][0] + "-col-" + snake.current_snake[i][1]).addClass("snake");
        break;
    }
  }
}

function createFood() {
  food.position[0] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 0)) + 0;
  food.position[1] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 0)) + 0;
  $("#row-" + food.position[0] + "-col-" + food.position[1]).addClass("food");

  console.log(food.position);
}

function collisionDetection() {
  for (var i = 0; i < snake.current_snake.length; i++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(snake.current_snake[i]) ===
      JSON.stringify(i)) {
      return true
    }
  }
}

function gameOver() {
  if (snake.current_snake[0][0] > 39 || snake.current_snake[0][0] < 0 ||
    snake.current_snake[0][1] > 39 || snake.current_snake[0][1] < 0) {
    alert("Game Over");
    return true;
  } else if (collisionDetection() === true) {
    alert("Game Over");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function gameLoop() {
  setTimeout(function run() {
    if (gameOver() === false) {
      move();

      if (eatFood() === true) {
        createFood();
      }

      // gameLoop();
    }
  }, gameSpeed);

}

function eatFood() {
  if (JSON.stringify(snake.current_snake[0]) === JSON.stringify(food.position)) {
    var coord;

    switch (snake.direction) {
      case "l":
        coord = [snake.current_snake[0][0], snake.current_snake[0][1] - 1];
        break;
      case "u":
        coord = [snake.current_snake[0][0] - 1, snake.current_snake[0][1]];
        break;
      case "r":
        coord = [snake.current_snake[0][0], snake.current_snake[0][1] + 1];
        break;
      case "d":
        coord = [snake.current_snake[0][0] + 1, snake.current_snake[0][1]];
        break;
    }

    snake.current_snake.unshift(coord);
    $("#row-" + food.position[0] + "-col-" + food.position[1]).removeClass("food");
    console.log(food.position);

    return true;
  }
}

$(function() {
  render();
  // gameLoop();

  $("html").on("keyup", function(e) {
    gameLoop();
    e.preventDefault();
    parseKey(e.keyCode);
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.snake-grid {
  width: 502px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square {
  height: 12.5px;
  width: 12.5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.snake {
  background-color: yellow;
  &:after {
    content: "O";
  }
}

.food {
  background-color: red;
  &:after {
    content: "x";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snake-grid"></div>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be useful here

Comment: This is far too much code to expect us to debug for you. Have you done any debugging? Can you narrow down the problem any?

Comment: Please see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and as mentioned demonstrate the issue with either a jsfiddle or a build-in snippet in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is a codepen of my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmJWOa

Comment: Haven´t looked at your code, but the best way to do it is to move your tail to the place your head should be on move and all other cells stay the same. You might need to change tail and head classes though, as well as change/keep track which one is head and which one is tail